# OpenJPA - how to set the value of an auto-increment fields if needed

Tags: java, jpa, auto-increment, openjpa

I have set up my OpenJPA orm.xml to map an entity that has its primary key as an auto-increment value. I'm using a

```
    <id name="objectId">
      <column name="ObjectId"/>
      <generated-value strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
```

attribute and it all works nice and dandy.

However, in some cases I'm wishing to set a specific ObjectId (one that had been used and then the record was deleted). Is this possible? Should I create a new entity for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I create a new entity for this?

No, that would be an awful hack. Of course it would take an awful hack anyway, but I would rather go with a small native query:

- Create the object (with as little data as possible) in the native query using [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).
- Then load the entity by id with [`EntityManager.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find%28java.lang.Class%2C%20java.lang.Object%29).
- Now add the rest of the data.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to try this.